# React form checkbox delete or add, does not update on first interaction

Tags: reactjs

I have a form and checkbox's that I create from an array using map. The point of the checkboxes is if checked remove item from array if not checked add it back to array. So every onChange I check if it is checked or not and do that work, but the way it works now is the first checkbox I check it will not remove or add the item, but after that it will work like its supposed to work.

```js
const {query} = useRouter();
let queryCopy =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(query));

const [stateEditedQuery, setStateEditedQuery] = useState(query);

const tagDeletion = (e, tag) => {

  console.log(e, tag);
  if(e) {
  
    let index = query.tags.indexOf(tag);
    query.tags.splice(index, 1);
    
  } else {
  
    if(query.tags.indexOf(tag) === -1) query.tags.push(tag);
    
  }
  
  setStateEditedQuery(query);
  console.log("THIS HRERE", query.tags);
};

<fieldset>
  <legend>Delete Tags</legend>
  {query.tags?.map((tag, index) => {
    return (
      <Checkbox 
        labelText={tag} 
        id={index} 
        key={index} 
        onChange={(e) => tagDeletion(e, tag)}
        />
    )
  })}
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a relatively common problem including the useState hook, what you should do is update the current state like so:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string[]>([]);
const handleChange = (id: string) => {
  setValue(curr =>
    curr.includes(id)
      ? // when checkbox is already checked
        curr.filter(x => x !== id)
      : // when checkbox is to be checked
        [...curr, id]
  );
};
```

if you are not using Typescript, just omit the type definitions. Default state should be handled just by checking if
`value.includes(id)`.

Comment: Don't say "you should mutate". Mutating is bad in React, you create copies from your state and handle these copies to create a the next state